# Making An md5 hash of hashes

Tags: c#, php, hash, md5

I'm currently working on a C# application that sends a request to a php webserver which then validates a MySQL connection. The hashing algorithm is on the server, which works fine, but I want the same hashing technique in my C# application. The md5 hashing is from ipBoard forums, which is why it needs to be this one specifically. Here's how it states according to them:

"The hash is the md5 sum of the md5 sum of the salt concatenated to the md5 sum of the plaintext password. Expressed in PHP code, this is as follows:
$hash = md5( md5( $salt ) . md5( $password ) ); "

I just don't know where to start with this in c#.. Thanks for any responses.

Comment: So you want the PHP script to validate the MySQL connection string that was passed to it by the C# application?

Comment: No the connection string is server sided. The application is passing a username and password. I want to hash the password to prevent a man in the middle attack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need a quick, ported version of the supplied PHP code:

```
// Create the MD5 hash object.
System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create ();

string password = "password";
string salt = "salt";

// Hash password and salt
byte[] passwordHash = md5.ComputeHash (System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (password));
byte[] saltHash = md5.ComputeHash (System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (salt));

// Combine password and hash.
string passwordAndSalt = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString (passwordHash) + System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString (saltHash);

// Compute final hash against the password and salt.
byte[] finalHash = md5.ComputeHash (System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (passwordAndSalt));
```

See the [System.Security.Cryptography.MD5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) docs for more info.

Comment: I'd add that the submitter could avoid this complexity by sending the plaintext password over a secured connection instead. This implementation will need modifying if the IP.Board hashing algorithm changes in future, for example.